# Orocommerce installed. But Symfony Permission denied, Failed to read session data

Tags: symfony, orocommerce

After installed orocommerce, i input the URL and want to visit my domain, then error occurred.

Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/www/wwwroot/mydomain.com/var/sessions/prod/sess_u8756ela11vqu4ihcokmklo9b8, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /www/wwwroot/mydomain.com/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Handler/StrictSessionHandler.php on line 49

Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /www/wwwroot/mydomain.com/var/sessions/prod) in /www/wwwroot/mydomain.com/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php on line 149

```
**StrictSessionHandler.php on line 49 is**     
return $this->handler->read($sessionId);

**NativeSessionStorage.php on line 149 is**
if (!session_start()) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to start the session.');
    }
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

"Permission denied" means the webserver has no access to the sessions folder.

You have to [set up permissions properly](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/installation/#set-up-file-permissions) or change the user used for the webserver.